# Bower, GIT and Grunt install, do all projects etc need to be in same directory?

Tags: git, cmd, gruntjs, bower

I installed GIT, and Bower and Grunt on my C: drive.  I used GitBash to install clone a project into a folder on another drive (in this case my f:/ drive).  When I try to run a Bower install in my cloned project folder, it gives me a  'git is not installed or in the PATH'.  Does this mean that my cloned project folder has to also be in my C:/Drive?  Or should I start over and install everything on my F:/ drive?

A little new to using GIT, Bower, and Grunt via CMD.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I chose the wrong way to install GIT. I ended up reinstalling msysgit and chose to use Windows command prompt as the installer.  Now the Bower Install command worked targeting the separate drive.